# I want to get term by term_name without taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms, wpdb

Can I get the term by it's id without knowing to which taxonomy it belongs?

I have a meta field that stores term names, but doesn't store the taxonomy. However, all the `get_term()` function have taxonomy parameter marked as required.

Maybe I can get the taxonomy of the term by it's (the term's) name somehow?

I'm trying:

```
$term_names = ['red','blue'];
$term_datas = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "SELECT t.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t WHERE t.name = $term_names"
) );
var_dump($term_datas);
```

Comment: Your meta field should store the term ID, not the name. Storing names is a bad idea when IDs are available. Everything but the ID is subject to change.

Comment: Thanks. I want to search by term_name this time.

Comment: This is because we want to search which Taxonomy and term_id from the input term_name.

Comment: Term name is ambiguous even within same taxonomy. Traffic patrol officer to the other: Stop the white car! Which of tehm? The white!
You are doing it wrong. Can't be solved properly. All you an get is one or more of the term(s) with that name.

Comment: The same term_name does not exist.So I want to search by term_name.

Answer (score 0):

The [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) function does not accept a string or array; it only accepts an ID, a stdClass object or a WP_Term object. So I think you're headed in the right direction using `$wpdb`. But the SQL query can't accept a PHP array. So try this:

```
$term_names = ['red','blue'];
$term_names_str = implode(', ', $term_names);
$term_datas = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name IN ($term_names_str)"
) );
var_dump($term_datas);
```

Note, you were using the `get_row` method, which would only retrieve one result; `get_results` will retrieve all results rows matching the query.